# In Ubuntu 16.04 LTS HP LaserJet MFP M436dn Printer does not include Hplip. What can I do?

Tags: printing

[image]

> Printer name mfp m436dn not found in hplip 3.18.6

Comment: Have you tried installing the printer through CUPS instead?  http://localhost:631/admin

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an entry for the MFP M436dn in the hplip list of supported printers; it looks like it does A3 from a SA website selling it

if the devices have MFP in their title, they often need a plug-in

so: if you open a terminal; (hold down the control and alt and t keys together) and then type`hp-setup` that should prompt hp-setup to run; and if a plug-in is needed, it should offer to get that and install it for you and it should do the setup for you

let us know how this goes